# Support for go file watchers with directly mounted CIFS shares

Tags: mount, samba, docker, cifs

I am currently working with `cifs-utils` to manage CIFS shares in a Unix environment, specifically within Docker containers (ubuntu docker host). I am exploring the possibility of integrating a file watching mechanism to monitor changes in these CIFS shares directly from within the containers and interested in detecting events such as file creation, modification, and deletion in real-time.
Given the `cifs-utils` capabilities and the nature of CIFS/SMB protocols, I would like to know if there is a recommended approach or existing support for such functionality.
Any advice, suggestions, or pointers towards relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [`inotifywait`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/inotifywait.1.html)